# Create loop to return return key-value-pair-XML-elements generically

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, export

How can I create a loop inside a Scalar-valued Function to return key-value-pair-XML-elements generically?

My function currently looks like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCustomXML]
(
    @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (
    SELECT (

    SELECT
    --Table A
    (SELECT [DataItemName] = CASE WHEN [TableA].[Address] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Address' END,
            [DataItemValue] = [TableA].[Address]
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM'), TYPE),
    --Table B
    (SELECT [DataItemName] = CASE WHEN [TableB].[Name] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Name' END,
            [DataItemValue] = [TableB].[Name]
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM'), TYPE),
    ....

FROM [TableA] LEFT JOIN 
[TableB] ON [TableA].[ID] = [TableB].[ID]
FOR XML PATH('OTHER'), ROOT('EXTENSION'), TYPE );

END;
```

As you can see I have to specifically write down the path for each variable. I want a loop which I only have to write once that inputs the path to each variable.

This is the result that I want:

```
<OTHER>
<EXTENSION>
<CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
   <DataItemName>Address</DataItemName> (variable name)
   <DataItemValue>12800 Apple Dr. Houston TX, 77483</DataItemValue> (value inside table column)
</CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
<CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
   <DataItemName>Name</DataItemName>
   <DataItemValue>David</DataItemValue>
</CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
</OTHER>
</EXTENSION>
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data that relates to your desired output.

Comment: Thanks @Matt I have edited the question. My desired output is at the bottom.

Comment: The desired output is a little more clear than before but I understood that part.  I am asking for INPUT/sample data to see how you want the data transformed because what you are showing can probably be done a different more efficient way depending on your input data.

Comment: Well the input data is obtained through a UI and stored in the corresponding table/column. So for example there is a field called Name and the user puts their name in. From there I just pull it from the column. I'm not sure how I would show sample data. Is this what you were referring to? @Matt

Comment: @Matt The name value format which I provided can't be changed due to some requirements.

Comment: Yes I am asking for you to post a few rows (or example) rows from tables that are involved so that we as a community can help you reach your desired result.  You should be able to do a Select of a sub select with union and generate the correct XML.  No loops!

Comment: Hi, is this question still open? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, which is not very clear, I take, that you are looking for generic approach to achieve what you need.

#### This is the approach I told you in the last question:

Test table

```
CREATE TABLE Test1(ID INT, TestVarchar VARCHAR(100),TestDate DATE);
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES
 (1,'Test 1',{d'2016-01-01'})
,(2,'Test 2',{d'2016-02-02'});
```

From your function I take, that you want one single row
But this approach would work for many rows as well

```
SELECT 'ID' AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemName]
      ,ID AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemValue]
      ,''
      ,'TestVarchar' AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemName]
      ,TestVarchar AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemValue]
      ,''
      ,'TestDate' AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemName]
      ,TestDate AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemValue]
FROM Test1
WHERE ID=2
FOR XML PATH('EXTENSION'),ROOT('OTHER');
GO
```

The result

```
<OTHER>
  <EXTENSION>
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
      <DataItemName>ID</DataItemName>
      <DataItemValue>2</DataItemValue>
    </CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
      <DataItemName>TestVarchar</DataItemName>
      <DataItemValue>Test 2</DataItemValue>
    </CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
    <CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
      <DataItemName>TestDate</DataItemName>
      <DataItemValue>2016-02-02</DataItemValue>
    </CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM>
  </EXTENSION>
</OTHER>
```

Now you are asking for a loop. I think - what you really want - is a generical approach not to type all column names manually.
This is **not possible on normal ways!!**

But there is a possibilty with dynamically creates statements. One big backdraw: **This will - for sure - not work within a scalar function!** You'll have to call a stored procedure and use output parameters to hand your result out.

So: we need the table's name and the ID (and quite probably you'll need the name of the ID column variable too):

```
DECLARE @tblNm VARCHAR(100)='Test1';
DECLARE @ID INT=2;
```

--Now we *create the statement from above as string*

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT 'SELECT '
    + STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ',''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS  [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemName],'
                 + COLUMN_NAME + ' AS [CUSTOM_DATA_ITEM/DataItemValue],'''''
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=@tblNm 
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,'')  
    + ' FROM ' + @tblNm + ' WHERE ID=''' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(100)) + ''' FOR XML PATH(''EXTENSION''),ROOT(''OTHER'');'
);
```

--And execute it

```
EXEC (@cmd);
GO
```

--Clean up

```
DROP TABLE Test1;
```

As the command is the same as before, the result is it as well...

Comment: That is great information. I will have to read more on dynamic sql and differences between scalar and non scalar functions. Thanks for the help @Shnugo